# Let $X$ and $Y$ normed spaces and $T:X\rightarrow Y$ one bounded surjective linear transformation. Show that they are equivalent:

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

$(I)$ $T$ is reversible and $T^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ is bounded.

$(II)$ Exists $b>0$ such that $||T(x)||\geq b||x||,\forall x\in X.$

$(III)$ All linear inverse on right of $T$ is bounded, and $$\sup \{||S||: S\text{ is linear inverse on right of }T\}.$$

I proved that $(I)\Leftrightarrow(II)\Rightarrow (III)$. Now, I triyng prove that $(III)\Rightarrow (II)$ or $(III)\Rightarrow (I)$.

Comment: Is there meant to be $< \infty$ in (III)?

Comment: What did you get so far?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Im trying use $||T(x)||\leq ||T|| ||x||$ and surjective $T^{1}(y)=x$ for some $y\in Y$.

Comment: @KennyLau I dont know! maybe have one error. But, in my exercise I do not have this hypothesis. You mean dim$X<+\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ is not injective, and let $U$ be a bounded right inverse, and $e\in Ker(T), \|e\|=1$. Let $\alpha$ be a bounded non zero $1$-form defined on $Y$, defined $U_n(x)=U(x)+n\alpha(x)e$, $U_n$ is a right inverse and the sequence $U_n$ is not bounded since $\|U_n(x)|\geq |n\alpha(x)\|-\|U(x)\|$. If $\|x\|=1$ and $\alpha(x)\neq 0$, $lim_n\|U_n(x)\|=+\infty$. Contradiction.

Comment: I couldn't understand how $U_n$ is a inverse on right of $T$.

Comment: $TU_n(x)=T(U_n(x)+n\alpha(x)e)=TU(x)+n\alpha(x)T(e)=TU(x)=x$.

Comment: Oh man! thanks! you are my Hero!